# NEXTJS Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: games.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm trying build my first website that displays data from an api without a tutorial. Am I missing something?

I fetched the api correctly, the console log prints the data I need but when I try to display it, it gives me the games.map is not a function error.

```
'use client'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export default function Home() {
  const [games, setGames] = useState([])

  const apiKey = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RAWG_API_KEY
  const url = `https://rawg-video-games-database.p.rapidapi.com/games?key=${apiKey}`

  useEffect(() => {
    const options = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'X-RapidAPI-Key': process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RAPID_API_KEY,
        'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'rawg-video-games-database.p.rapidapi.com',
      },
    }

    fetch(url, options)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.results[0])
        setGames(response.results[0])
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err)
      })
  }, [])

  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
      {games &&
        games.map((game) => {
          return (
            <div key={game.id}>
              <h1>{game.name}</h1>
            </div>
          )
        })}
    </main>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error happens when the data is not an array and in this example for a high chance the data (`response.results[0]`) is an object instead of an array.